# How to write byte[] to PDF document using itextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a byte[] and I want to write **byte[]** to PDF document. I have seen Paragraph, ShowText methods to print text but I don't know how to pass byte[]. In the below code, I want to write **fileBytes** to PDF. How to do that?

```
            BaseFont f_cb = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\calibrib.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            BaseFont f_cn = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\calibri.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\196836f7-9cf5-4044-b11e-2e3d06888c43.pdf");

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\result_196836f7-9cf5-4044-b11e-2e3d06888c43.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            {
                Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 25, 25, 30, 30);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);

                // Add meta information to the document
                document.AddAuthor("John");
                document.AddCreator("itestSharp demo");
                document.AddKeywords("ItextSharp tutorial");
                document.AddSubject("Steps to write byte[] to PDF using c#");
                document.AddTitle("Steps to write byte[] to PDF using c#");

                document.Open();

                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                cb.SetFontAndSize(f_cb, 16);

                cb.BeginText();

                cb.SetTextMatrix(25, 400);                
                cb.ShowText("Hello World");

                cb.EndText();                

                document.Close();
                writer.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }
```

Comment: As what do you want to print those bytes? Do you want to fill the PDF with an hex dump of them?

Comment: @mkl My target is to make another pdf with different page size than the original. My original pdf has A4 page size and I want to create another pdf with US Letter page size and rewrite contents from original pdf. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Well, if your PDF has enough free space at the top and the bottom, you can simply change the dimensions of the page and leave the contents as they are. Or you could scale the A4 page down a bit to definitively fit into the Letter page. Trying to reflow PDF contents, though, in generally is hard to implement. Either way, though, in neither case "writing byte[] to PDF document" is part of a solution, you really should re-build / [edit] your post and ask your actual question.